# internal server errors - Premature end of script headers: cgi_wrapper

Tags: php, cgi, cgi-bin, internal-server-error

My website is getting random internal server errors only on php pages. In the log it says this is being caused by 'Premature end of script headers: cgi_wrapper'.

This issue is completely random, but consistently occuring. One second a page will work, the next it throws out the error. If a number of people visit the website at once, 80% of those people receive the internal server error, but works for them sooner or later.

Any information I find on this does not seem to be for cases where the error is displaying randomly.

When looking into 'Premature end of script headers: cgi_wrapper' there seems to be so many different possibilities. I know my question is too vague for a straight answer.. I'm just looking for someone to give me an idea of the direction I should head in.

Comment: PHP crashes before the webserver recieves something useful to return to the client (webbrowser). I'd say your host is running out of resources. Switch the SAPI, try with FCGI instead of CGI. Contact your hoster anyway, you need to clarify this with her.